# XSLT - Here's a true challenge for XSLT transformation with optional element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm lost with a difficult XSLT transformation.

This is my input file:

```
<block>
    <item>
        <name>item1</name>
        <place>place1</place>
    </item>

    <item>
        <name>item2</name>
        <comment>comment2</comment>
        <place>place2</place>
    </item>

    <item>
        <name>item3</name>
        <stick>stick3</stick>
       <place>place3</place>
    </item>
    ...
</block>
```

There are any blocks 'item':

- **name** is mandatory
- **comment** is optional
- **stick** is optional
- **place** is mandatory
- **order** is very important (a DTD file validates this XML)!

My issue: for each **item** element, I want to insert an element **stick**:

```
<stick>default</stick>
```

- This element **stick** has to be after element **comment** if exists it or after the node **name** else.
- If element **stick** already exists, then the **item** element doesn't have to be modified.

To resume, my output file has to be:

```
<block>
    <item>
        <name>item1</name>
        <stick>default</stick>
        <place>place1</place>
    </item>

    <item>
        <name>item2</name>
        <comment>comment2</comment>
        <stick>default</stick>
        <place>place2</place>
    </item>

    <item>
        <name>item3</name>
        <stick>stick3</stick>
        <place>place3</place>
    </item>
    ...
</block>
```

I already tried a lot of XSLT transformations but impossible to have the expected result :-(

Any ideas?

Regards,
Zido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[not(stick)]/comment | item[not(stick or comment)]/name">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <stick>default</stick>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. It works perfectly! And one more time, I see I want to do too complex. I don't have the philosophy "templates". It's very basic in fact. Thank you for everything.

Comment: PS: I don't understand why some people voted negatively for my question...

Comment: @zido71 - I dont understand either, so I used my vote to help redress the balance.